# Parse malformed HTML using Dart

Tags: html, dart

So I have this code inside of a class file:

```
Document requestData (String url, [String postVars, bool pauseApp = false, onSuccess(Document ht)]) {
   HttpRequest html = new HttpRequest();
   html.open((postVars == null ? 'GET' : 'POST'), url, async: !pauseApp);

   html.send(postVars);
   if (pauseApp == true) { return html.responseXML; }
   else { html.on.readyStateChange.add((Event e) { 
             if (html.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE && (html.status == 200 || html.status == 0)) {
                 try { 
                   //HERE IS WHERE THE ISSUE IS ----V
                   DOMParser d = new DOMParser();
                   onSuccess(d.parseFromString(html.responseText,"text/html")); 
                   }
                 catch (e) {
                   print("Error on requestData($url) async = $pauseApp - $e");
                 }
               }
           });
     }
 }
```

(Entire source for reference: http://pastebin.com/z21PM7r0 - I am using the dartium flag '--disable-web-security' to allow cross server requests)

The issue is basically, the requests responseXML returns null whereas the responseText returns the HTML as expected. To combat this I attempted to use the DOM parser and that failed.

As I don't own or control the server I need to connect to I cannot fix the html myself. The issue I assume is because its malformed.

Here is the code of the website I am trying to parse using the function above:
http://pastebin.com/KvMN9AuF

W3 Validator gives: 193 Errors, 16 warning(s)

Does anybody know how to combat this issue? Or is this something I am just going to have to give up on...

Comment: It would help if you explained what your end goal is here? What do you want to extract out of the HTML being sent to you?

Comment: Well Im going to be using the function "requestData" throughout my code to get pages from the site. Really I need it to be as if I was extracting data from a normal webpage, I know I could use regex or something but that just seems messy and very easilly broken if the site updates.

Comment: Sure, but what do you want to do with the data you retrieve with requestData? Do you want to be able to parse it as XML? Extract some specific value from it? Create DOM elements and add it to the page?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I just need to be able to query it and extract data. For example to check I am logged into the site I would simply query("title") and then get the innerHTML value and check for the logged in title. Basically I need it to return a object of the "Document" class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [html5lib](https://github.com/dart-lang/html5lib). It's a spec-compliant html5 parser in pure Dart. You should be able to read in the malformed html, and then use document.outerHtml to get a well-formed String.

Comment: Awesome exactly what I needed! Couldn't find it on Google oddly enough... Just came up with the default implementations.

Comment: I seem the `html5lib` moved to http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/html5lib from github.

Answer (score 1):

If I were in your shoes, I'd take one of these approaches:

- If you happen to be using Python on your server, then you can use lxml with the Beautiful Soup parser to parse the HTML and get whatever information you want from it.
- Figure out what you want from the HTML and use regexes. Make sure you turn on multiline mode so that you can run the regex against the whole document instead of one line at a time. Yes, this is fragile, but how fragile depends on what data you want and what kind of regex you use to get it.
- Port Beautiful Soup to Dart and become an instant celebrity in the Dart world ;)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The server isn't mine and I cant pass it through another server (as it has IP blocks in place). As you say regex is very fragile and the site updates rather often too which would make it a nightmare to update. The answer I chose actually showed [html5lib](https://github.com/dart-lang/html5lib) which is a port of pythons html5lib so I suppose they are a celebrity in the Dart world :P

Comment: Duh, I should have known about that!